# What is the Purpose of using multidex support library? [ I referred official android site for this.]

Tags: android

I referred the [Android Documentation site.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for "Multidex" but not getting idea when i use this. and it is mandatory to use this or not.For what purpose we need to use that class??

Thanks..

Comment: You will only need to use it, when the number of methods in your app exceeds 64K.

Comment: generally you should keep your method count down to below 64K. Use proguard to remove and obfuscate your code. In case you exceed 64k method count you can use multi dex.

Comment: if the number of methods are below 64K, then i doesn't want to use this??

Comment: No you shouldn't. I use use multidex only as a last resort. See @Knossos answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of this is to split up your Dex file into multiple Dex files.

The Dex file contains the compiled code of your application.

Android has a problem whereby there is an upper limit on the number of method definitions in a Dex file (64k). This means that once that limit is reached, you cannot expand your application any further.

Before multidex, it was advised to use ProGuard to reduce the number of method definitions by removing methods that aren't used in code. Especially useful when implementing the Google Play Services Framework.

Multidex was then introduced and allows Apps to continue to expand without worrying about method count limits. **It does carry the danger of making the App more unstable.** Therefore it is advised to try ProGuard first to reduce the method count.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

according to documentation:

> Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in
>   the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled
>   code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits
>   the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX
>   file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods,
>   and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that
>   you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX
>   file, known as a multidex configuration.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. :)